# How to do distinct on multiple columns after join and then sort and select latest for each group?

Tags: sql, postgresql, scala, slick

I have these 3 tables. Given `Group Name` I would like to find all the products from `Product Table` for that group and then get the latest version from `Version table`

Product Group Table

```
id  group_name
---------------------------
1   Nice
2   Very Nice
```

Product table

```
prod_id  name      group_id
---------------------------
1       something     2
2       psp3          1
3.      other one     2
```

Version Table

```
id  prod_id    version
---------------------------
1   2           1.0
2   2           1.1
3   3           2.3
4   1           0.1
5.  1           0.2
```

e.g. Given Group Name `Very Nice`, output I would expect is

```
Group_name  prod_name    version
---------------------------------
Very Nice   something     0.2
Very Nice   other one     2.3
```

I was trying to do Join of all 3 tables and then distinct on and then sort by desc and select the first one. But I end up just getting 1 instead of the above result. Wondering what would the sql query look like? if it matters I am using PostgreSQL, Scala/Slick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (pg.id, p.prod_id)
    pg.group_name, p.name AS prod_name, v.version
FROM product_group pg
LEFT JOIN product p ON pg.id = p.group_id
LEFT JOIN version v ON v.prod_id = p.prod_id
ORDER BY pg.id, p.prod_id, v.version DESC;
```

[image: screen capture of demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: Thanks, But `v.version DESC` how do I select only the top one ? or this will do it and only give me only 1 version. Or will it give me multiple versions for same group_id,prod_id?

Comment: @user2616355 Please reload to see the updated working answer.  It is sometimes hard to get code completely right the very first time.

Comment: Awesome! thanks this works! If I need to enhance the query so it returns all other columns from Version table along with just the `version` . Is there a way I can get those too ?

Comment: Well, if you just want to see all columns from the `version` table, then edit the select list and use `v.*` instead of `v.version`.